# Custom Standard Errors with Statsmodels / Stargazer

Tags: python, overriding, statsmodels, stargazer, standard-error

I am running a series of OLS regressions in Python, where I am using standard errors that I calculate using a custom function.

I am now exporting my regression results into tables, and plan on using the stargazer package (linked [`here`](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer)). However, stargazer relies on regression results being calculated via the statsmodels package.

I am having trouble incorporating my custom standard errors into statsmodels, and hence cannot export using stargazer. I have tried looking if there is a way to overwrite default standard errors in statsmodels, but have not been successful.

I've provided example below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import statsmodels.api as sm
from stargazer.stargazer import Stargazer

#load data
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
df = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data)
df.columns = ['Age', 'Sex', 'BMI', 'ABP', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6']
df['target'] = diabetes.target

#run regressions with statsmodels
est = sm.OLS(endog=df['target'], exog=sm.add_constant(df[df.columns[0:4]])).fit()

#custom standard errors function, returns a K-by-1 vector where K is the number of predictors
#I return a vector of ones here for simplicity
def custom_standard_errors(endog, exog):
    return [1 for i in range(len(exog.columns))]
    
#export regression table with stargazer
stargazer = Stargazer([est])
```

The `stargazer` object is displayed below. My goal is to overwrite the standard errors in the parentheses with output from `custom_standard_errors()`. As such, every value in parentheses should be 1, in this example.

[image: Stargazer output]

Comment: can you provide an example of some of your code, or a minimum reproducible example of some of the custom standard errors you want to incorporate into `statsmodels / stargazer`? you could also use a small toy data set if sharing the actual data you're using is problematic

Comment: my feeling is that you could probably use inheritance to add new functionality to some of the class methods in the packages and libraries you're working with – as long as I have a bit more guidance or an example of what exactly you're looking for, i'd be happy to help!

Comment: Example now provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required some digging, but I believe I have a working solution.

When you create an instance of the `Stargazer` class such as your object `stargazer`, most of the regression results are [extracted](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/62135cf490911b13901099d483fc75db996f9002/stargazer/stargazer.py#L55) from the `est` object which is of type `ResultsWrapper` (from `statsmodels`).

Three instance methods called `extract_data`, `_extract_feature`, and `extract_model_data` are called and [extract_model_data](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/62135cf490911b13901099d483fc75db996f9002/stargazer/stargazer.py#L140-L182) does a lot of the heavy lifting: it specifically extracts features stored in `statsmodels_map`, which looks like the following:

```
statsmodels_map = {'p_values' : 'pvalues', ## ⭠ and this too
                   'cov_values' : 'params',
                   'cov_std_err' : 'bse', ## ⭠ we want to modify this 
                   'r2' : 'rsquared',
                   'r2_adj' : 'rsquared_adj',
                   'f_p_value' : 'f_pvalue',
                   'degree_freedom' : 'df_model',
                   'degree_freedom_resid' : 'df_resid',
                   'nobs' : 'nobs',
                   'f_statistic' : 'fvalue'
                   }
```

What we can do is create a child class called `SuperStargazer` that inherits all of the instance methods from `Stargazer`, and then override the `extract_model_data` to set `cov_std_err` using your `custom_standard_errors` function. Although it's not strictly necessary, we'll set `custom_standard_errors` as an instance attribute of the SuperStargazer class, as this allows you to use different custom functions if you define different instances of the `SuperStargazer` class.

Update: we'll also update the `p-values` as they are related to the new custom standard errors. This involves recalculating the `t-values`, and then applying the formula: `p_value = 2*(1 - t.cdf(abs(t_value), dof))`

```
from statsmodels.base.wrapper import ResultsWrapper
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import RegressionResults
from scipy.stats import t
from math import sqrt
from collections import defaultdict
from enum import Enum
import numbers
import pandas as pd

class SuperStargazer(Stargazer):
    def __init__(self, models, custom_standard_errors, **kwargs):
        self.custom_standard_errors = custom_standard_errors
        super().__init__(models=models, **kwargs)
    
    def extract_model_data(self, model):
        # For features that are simple attributes of "model", establish the
        # mapping with internal name (TODO: adopt same names?):
        statsmodels_map = {# 'p_values' : 'pvalues',
                           'cov_values' : 'params',
                           # 'cov_std_err' : 'bse',
                           'r2' : 'rsquared',
                           'r2_adj' : 'rsquared_adj',
                           'f_p_value' : 'f_pvalue',
                           'degree_freedom' : 'df_model',
                           'degree_freedom_resid' : 'df_resid',
                           'nobs' : 'nobs',
                           'f_statistic' : 'fvalue'
                           }

        data = {}
        for key, val in statsmodels_map.items():
            data[key] = self._extract_feature(model, val)

        if isinstance(model, ResultsWrapper):
            data['cov_names'] = model.params.index.values
            endog, exog = model.model.data.orig_endog, model.model.data.orig_exog
            custom_std_err_data = self.custom_standard_errors(endog, exog)
            data['cov_std_err'] = pd.Series(
                index=exog.columns,
                data=custom_std_err_data
            )
            data['t_values'] = data['cov_values'] / data['cov_std_err']
            dof = len(endog) - 2
            data['p_values'] = pd.Series(
                index=data['t_values'].index,
                data=2 * (1 - t.cdf(abs(data['t_values']), dof))
            )
            
        else:
            # Simple RegressionResults, for instance as a result of
            # get_robustcov_results():
            data['cov_names'] = model.model.data.orig_exog.columns

            # These are simple arrays, not Series:
            for what in 'cov_values', 'cov_std_err':
                data[what] = pd.Series(data[what],
                                       index=data['cov_names'])

        data['conf_int_low_values'] = model.conf_int()[0]
        data['conf_int_high_values'] = model.conf_int()[1]
        data['resid_std_err'] = (sqrt(sum(model.resid**2) / model.df_resid)
                                 if hasattr(model, 'resid') else None)

        # Workaround for
        # https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6778:
        if 'f_statistic' in data:
            data['f_statistic'] = (lambda x : x[0, 0] if getattr(x, 'ndim', 0)
                                   else x)(data['f_statistic'])

        return data
```

Then when we can create an instance of `SuperStargazer`, it will render the following table (in `JupyterLab` in my case, but you can also call `stargazer.render_html()` to store the html string for later use)

```
stargazer = SuperStargazer(
    models=[est], 
    custom_standard_errors=custom_standard_errors
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I may be able to make this correction myself, but realize it may be faster if I note this here as you may be able to help. The improvement I have in mind is that I would like the statistical significance stars above the coefficients to also change depending on the realized p-values. In particular, all coefficients in the example above should have *** (as the p-values are past the 1% level)

Comment: I am happy to have helped! Out of curiosity, are you calculating the p-values in a different manner from `statsmodels`? When I look into `superstargazer.model_data`, the calculated p-values seem to match those indicated by the table. that being said, [this](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/62135cf490911b13901099d483fc75db996f9002/stargazer/stargazer.py#L351-L361) is where the number of asterisks is being generated in the `stargazer` class

Comment: No, I'm calculating the p-values in the same way as in statsmodels (given the coefficient estimate, custom standard error, and the degrees of freedom).

Comment: in that case, I think a "patch" should work best – we can set `t_values = cov_values / cov_std_err` in the same place where we set the custom standard errors, then use something like `p_values = 2 * (1 - t.cdf(abs(data['t_values']), dof)`